# How to make database insert operation from TCP Server without affecting server performance

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5, tcpserver

I have designed the async tcp server in .net 4.5. with async await pattern using this [Link](https://bsmadhu.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/simplify-asynchronous-programming-with-c-5-asyncawait/),  at present multiple clients connects to server simultaneously  and send some string data.

At present I am displaying all received data on to console just for testing purpose

My server code is as below

```
public class AsyncEchoServer
{
    private int _listeningPort;
    public AsyncEchoServer( int port)
    {
        _listeningPort = port;
    }

    public async void Start()
    {

        IPAddress ipAddre = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.4");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddre, _listeningPort);
        listener.Start();
        LogMessage("Server is running");
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                 HandleConnectionAsync(tcpClient);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                LogMessage(exp.ToString());
            }

        }

    }

    private async void HandleConnectionAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        string clientInfo = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        try
        {

            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;
                while (true)
                {
                    var dataFromServer = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataFromServer))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    LogMessage(dataFromServer );
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync("FromServer-" + dataFromServer);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            LogMessage(exp.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
           tcpClient.Close();
        }

    }
    private void LogMessage(string message, [CallerMemberName]string callername = "")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[{0}] - Thread-{1}- {2}", callername, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, message);
    }
```

Now I want to design it in such way that data received from the client should be inserted into appropriate database tables.

But I am scared if this will low down the performance of my server as database operations are quite bulky. Can anybody suggest me what approach I should follow for processing the data received from multiple client.

I am thinking to make the use of datatable to insert all the incoming data into it and letter use to bulkinsert to insert the same in sql server

but I am not sure how to maintain the datatable for each connection, or even its good idea or not

I just don't know from where I suppose to start, Any valuable inputs would be really helpful

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an asynchronous TCP server. The obvious solution is to make the database access asynchronous as well - then the DB itself is your limit, not your server code. And unless you're making a chat for 50k simultaneous users, you're fine, really; otherwise, you'll need a lot more knowledge than just a simple tip from SO :)

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450432/async-tcp-server-in-net-4-5-using-asyn-and-await-data-loss-is-happening), Can you please go through this link and suggest me something.

Comment: I am trying to make database acess asynchronous but no success yet :( ,  Can you please provide some code snippet referring my edited code above.  I tried to create datatable and insert all the incoming data into it letter to make bulkcopy of it but it fails.

Comment: @HarshalSam All the usual methods have their async counterparts - `DbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync`, `DbDataReader.ReadAsync` etc. The only ones that don't are the like of `SqlDataAdapter`, which probably has a lot to do with the fact that both the data adapters and the data tables were pretty much replaced by later technologies like LINQ-to-SQL and Entity Framework. However, if you want to stick to the archaic approach, it shouldn't really be hard to make your own async methods to handle that - the data adapters are very simple, really.

Comment: Thanks, It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use async-await for this task I think.
You should start new Thread for each client connection

```
 // Get new client
 TcpClient Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
 // Create Thread
 Thread Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ClientThread));
 // Start Thread for this client
 Thread.Start(Client);
```

As you can see there is no point in async-await in created Thread.

Comment: This is *exactly* the scenario for using async-await. Why would you start a new thread when you have no CPU work to do?

Comment: @Luaan IMO async-await is more intended use with UI, to save contexts and perform I/O operations without UI lock. At least my experience with async-await and TcpServer was not so great. Do you have the decent example of TCPServer based on async-await maybe? Will examine it with pleasure.

Comment: async/await are great for any kind of asynchronous I/O operations. UI is sure one of them, but networking, filesystem etc. are other great examples. It saves resources and reduces code complexity in those cases as well.

Comment: Well, I'm working on a networking tutorial - https://github.com/Luaancz/Networking It's far from complete, and it's not tested nearly enough to be a real foundation for anything with more than about 1000 simultaneous clients (and even that would need better exception handling), but it shows the basic concepts. And even if you didn't use await, the older asynchronous APIs are a must for any networking server that's supposed to handle more than about 100 clients - await is much easier to use than this, of course.