# Async TCP Server in .net 4.5 using asyn and await, data loss is happening

Tags: c#, async-await, jmeter, .net-4.5, tcplistener

I have to implement asyn tcp serve in .net 4.5 using async & await for this by referring the [Link](https://bsmadhu.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/simplify-asynchronous-programming-with-c-5-asyncawait/)
 I have implemented the server

My server code is as below

```
public class AsyncEchoServer
{
    private int _listeningPort;
    public AsyncEchoServer( int port)
    {
        _listeningPort = port;
    }

    public async void Start()
    {

        IPAddress ipAddre = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.4");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddre, _listeningPort);
        listener.Start();
        LogMessage("Server is running");
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                 HandleConnectionAsync(tcpClient);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                LogMessage(exp.ToString());
            }

        }

    }

    private async void HandleConnectionAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        string clientInfo = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        try
        {
            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
            {
                writer.AutoFlush = true;
                while (true)
                {
                    var dataFromServer = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataFromServer))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    LogMessage(dataFromServer );
                await writer.WriteLineAsync("FromServer-" + dataFromServer);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            LogMessage(exp.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
        }

    }
    private void LogMessage(string message, [CallerMemberName]string callername = "")
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - Thread-{1}- {2}",callername, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, message);
        //System.Console.WriteLine(message);

    }
```

I am using Jmeter TCP Sample for testing, in this i have created some 200 Thread group which send the data to server after every specific interval.

When I mention very small string like "1", "HI1" in all thread groups it works perfectly fine but the problem is when i mention some big strings let say of 800-900 characters, data loss is happening only partial data is display and many times from 200 clients only 24~25 clients data is displayed on console

Here is the snap of JMeter string

[image: JMeter TCP Sample]

Can anyone please suggest what should be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't just with the console? Have you tried logging to separate files (one per connection) for example? That would at least make it easier to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: On the first spot I cannot see the problem; anyway I suggest to introduce a length byte and stay in the receive loop until all bytes have been read.

Comment: No I am not really sure, Let me take a look at that. Thanks

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks man, the problem was maybe with the console i used "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine" and everything worked fine. I would love to mark your comment as answer but i feel there is not option for this

Comment: I'd avoid using `StreamWriter` (and `StreamReader`) - it doesn't give you the information you need to know when the stream is closed. In particular, `string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataFromServer)` will also terminate the stream when you get an empty line. What's the default for the End of line? it has to be `\r\n` for `StreamReader.ReadLine` I think.